# Cannot assign a value of type "String" to type "UILabel" in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, uilabel, uint32

I'm making a program that 's about a math test random generator.
But while I was creating a random operation. I used arc4random_uniform() to create a random number. Here's the function.

```
func generateQuestion() {
        var randomoperation:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(3)
        if randomoperation == 0 {
            operation = "+"
        }
        if randomoperation == 1 {
            operation = "-"
        }
        if randomoperation == 2 {
            operation = "X"
        }
        if randomoperation == 3 {
            operation = "/"
        }
    }
```

This creates the error "Cannot assign a type of value "String" to type "UILabel" in swift"
How do you fix this?

Comment: If operation is your UILabel then writer text as  `operation.text`

Answer (score 1):

```
func generateQuestion() {
    switch arc4random_uniform(4) {
    case 0:
        operation.text = "+"
    case 1:
        operation.text = "-"
    case 2:
        operation.text = "X"
    case 3:
        operation.text = "/"
    default:
        operation.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `operation` is your label name so you can assign text to it this way:

```
func generateQuestion() {
    var randomoperation:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(3)
    if randomoperation == 0 {
        operation.text = "+"
    }
    if randomoperation == 1 {
        operation.text = "-"
    }
    if randomoperation == 2 {
        operation.text = "X"
    }
    if randomoperation == 3 {
        operation.text = "/"
    }
}
```

Read this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text) for more Information.